# display double escaped special characters - change &amp;quot; to " using Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, escaping, special-characters

I have a page developed by someone who is retiring. The page is programmed in ASP, and pulls info from a database we maintain. All special characters are double escaped, (i.e. &amp;quot; and &amp;amp;) so the browser is rendering as &quot; and &amp;.

I would like to switch the behavior to properly display " or & respectively.

The data is loaded into a table, and is wrapped in only in td /td

The simplest method for me would be javascript/jquery, but I cannot get it to work.

I have tried a few methods that i have found here on SO such as:

```
$('td').innerText.each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(text.replace('&amp;amp;', '&')); 
    $(this).text(text.replace('&amp;quot;', '"')); 
});
```

I haven't had luck so far. Any ideas?

Comment: I have tried a few methods, one being html() and also text(). updated question to show current script

Comment: Added codepen example - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwqPwz

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried unescape() method in Javascript?

Comment: unescape() is only decoding URLEncoded strings, not HTML Entity